# Mapping Thin - Sinatra app with apache httpd

Tags: apache, sinatra, thin

Recently I developed a Sinatra app that running under Thin.
On my local and test servers it runs ok, but when I add it to my production env, all resources from public dir is inaccessible.

I'm not a apache guy, so I'm a little lost here.

Here is what I did:

*httpd.conf*

```
...
ProxyPass /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:9194/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp/ http://127.0.0.1:9194/myapp
```

By doing this, I want that every request to mydomain.com/myapp/ be forward to myapp.
In my app dir a have a public directory, with all my css, js and image files.

So, when I point to http://mydomain.com/myapp/ the html comes, but no css, images and js.
On the other hand, if I point to 127.0.0.1 at port 9194 it works as it should.

So my question is, how can I configure my apache - or thin, or sinatra - so I can have access to my public content via ProxyPass?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this might be of any use by try adding a `/` at the end of the second argument for `ProxyPassReverse`. The Apache docs say that if the first argument has a trailing slash, the second one also should have one.

Comment: That's exactly what was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `/` at the end of the second argument for ProxyPassReverse. The [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) say that if the first argument has a trailing slash, the second one also should have one.